# Require local image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, webpack, file-upload

I am trying to load local JPG image by it's path that must be get from the props of the component. But when I try to do that, the image is not loaded and its src path looks like that:

```
Module {default: "/ff5a7601c48dcb99c92acfca45eb2439.png", __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
```

But when I use import statement, it outputs right path:

```
/fa8b72877658d9175b437ebb88e3ef2c.jpg
```

I can't use import, because I need to get the path in the body of the component. So, how can I properly load the file?

There are my JSX component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

import '../../../resources/scss/style.scss';

class ArticleCard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const { article } = this.props;

    return (
      <Card>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={require(article.imagePath)} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{article.title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{article.description}</Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}

export default ArticleCard;
```

and webpack.config.js fragment:

```
{
   test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|jpg)$/i,
   use: {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
         name: 'client/resources/images/[name].[ext]',
         outputPath: 'dist/img/',
      },
   },
},
```

Comment: Which starter are you using? Why you configure webpack? Do you use CRA? It comes out of the box

Comment: I've configured webpack.config.js by myself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found a solution. `require` returns an object and image's path can be ejected from its `default` property:

```
<img src={require('path/to/img.png').default} />
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this solution tonight as well. Don't remember always having to do this.

Comment: Took a while to figure what was happening, this solution solves my problem. Also happening with dynamics imports "import().then ..."